# Combine coverage reports into one xml in python

Tags: python, coverage.py

my python project is composed of several different packages

```
main_dir
|- package_1
|- package_2
|_ package_3
```

i'm testing each package separately with pytest and pytest-cov

```
python -m pytest package_1\tests --junitxml package_1\test_result.xml --cov package_1 --cov-branch --cov-report xml:package_1\test_coverage.xml
python -m pytest package_2\tests --junitxml package_2\test_result.xml --cov package_2 --cov-branch --cov-report xml:package_2\test_coverage.xml
python -m pytest package_3\tests --junitxml package_3\test_result.xml --cov package_3 --cov-branch --cov-report xml:package_3\test_coverage.xml
```

this produces separate **test_coverage.xml** and **.coverage** file for each package

i want to merge the test coverage files into one xml file

what i did:

```
coverage combine package_1\.coverage package_2\.coverage package_3\.coverage
```

which works, generating a new **.coverage** file in my working directory, but then if I run:

```
coverage xml .coverage
```

i get this error:

```
Couldn't parse 'C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\git\main_dir\.coverage' as Python source: 'EOF in multi-line statement' at line 6580
```

Any idea on how I can achieve what i want? Is it possible to combine the xml files directly into one without passing through the .coverage files?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `coverage xml` command doesn't take the name of a data file as an argument.  The arguments are module names:

```
    $ coverage xml --help
    Usage: coverage xml [options] [modules]

    Generate an XML report of coverage results.

    Options:
      --data-file=INFILE    Read coverage data for report generation from this
                            file. Defaults to '.coverage'. [env: COVERAGE_FILE]
      --fail-under=MIN      Exit with a status of 2 if the total coverage is less
                            than MIN.
      -i, --ignore-errors   Ignore errors while reading source files.
      --include=PAT1,PAT2,...
                            Include only files whose paths match one of these
                            patterns. Accepts shell-style wildcards, which must be
                            quoted.
      --omit=PAT1,PAT2,...  Omit files whose paths match one of these patterns.
                            Accepts shell-style wildcards, which must be quoted.
      -o OUTFILE            Write the XML report to this file. Defaults to
                            'coverage.xml'
      -q, --quiet           Don't print messages about what is happening.
      --skip-empty          Skip files with no code.
      --debug=OPTS          Debug options, separated by commas. [env:
                            COVERAGE_DEBUG]
      -h, --help            Get help on this command.
      --rcfile=RCFILE       Specify configuration file. By default '.coveragerc',
                            'setup.cfg', 'tox.ini', and 'pyproject.toml' are
                            tried. [env: COVERAGE_RCFILE]
```

A plain `coverage xml` command should be enough.  Does it not work?

Comment: if i try:
coverage xml --data-file=.coverage
or simply:
coverage xml
i get:
No data to report